# What's {notification} in phpfox?

Tags: phpfox

Can someone explain to me why we use this instruction `{notification}` in the code of phpfox? For example in this code we use `{notification}`:

```
{if Phpfox::isUser() && !Phpfox::getUserBy('profile_page_id')}
getFullControllerName() == 'appletjava.index'} style="float: right;position: absolute;right: 199px;top: 7px;left:auto;" {/if}>  
{notification}
{/if}
```

We can found other keywords also that use `{}` I want to know what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all the {something} in phpfox templates get replaced for php code at "compilation" time. To learn what all the possibilities and replacements are open the file /include/library/phpfox/template/cache.class.php

For this specific question you will find it in line 1261 and it gets replaced for:

```
return '<?php Phpfox::getBlock(\'core.template-notification\'); ?>';
```

Comment: thank you so much for ure enriches explanation . it's clear :)

Comment: if this solved your question please mark it so the question gets closed properly. Have a good day!

Comment: (please mark it so the question gets closed properly)... how do it ??? i'm a new member here  !!! and thx for help

Comment: With pleasure! 
To the left you see two arrows, one to up vote the answer and another to down vote (if its a bad answer), under the down vote there is a check mark, if you see it and want to mark this answer as the one that helped you the most just mark the check